# C -Print contents of a csv file

Tags: c, csv, char

I am new to C and am struggling to print out the contents of a csv file. The file contains 2 columns and 6 rows. The first row contains the customers name and budget, and I can get that to print out. The remaining rows contain a products name and quantity I would like to purchase I think the problem might be with my for loop as it is not moving past the first row. I have been at this for a few days now.

Any help would be appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct Customer {
    char* name;
    double budget;
    char* product[5];
    int quantity;
    int index;

};

struct Customer custOrder()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t read;

    fp = fopen("customerkim.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    read = getline(&line, &len, fp);
    char *a = strtok(line, ",");
    char *b = strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *custName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
    double custBudget = atof(b);
    strcpy(custName, a);

    while((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        char *c = strtok(line, ",");
        char *d = strtok(NULL, ",");
        int custQuantity = atoi(d);
        char * custProduct = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
        strcpy(custProduct, c);
        struct Customer customer = {custName, custBudget, custProduct, custQuantity};
        struct Customer productItem = {product};
        customer.product[customer.index++] = productItem;
    }
    return customer;
}

void printCustomer(struct Customer c)
{
    printf("CUSTOMER NAME: %s \nCUSTOMER BUDGET: %.2f\n", c.name, c.budget);
    printf("___________________\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < c.index; i++)
    {
        struct Customer product = c.product[i]
            printf("%s ORDERS %d of %s\n", c.name, c.quantity, c.product);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Customer customer = custOrder();
    printCustomer(customer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should start by compiling with warnings enabled, and fix the problems the compiler will happily tell you about.

Comment: `customer` is local to the `while` loop. You can't access it after the loop is done.

Comment: Why do you have only one quantity in the structure? Shouldn't there be a quantity for each product?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` has been defined as 1 since at least 1989, and probably since the first day Ken touched a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `customer` variable outside the `while` loop. You're creating a new variable each time through the loop, so it doesn't retain the values from the previous iteration, and you can't return it after the loop is done.

There's only one `quantity` in the `Customer` structure, so I'm guessing it should be the total of all product quantities. So you need to add to that element, not assign it directly.

```
struct Customer custOrder()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    size_t read;

    fp = fopen("customerkim.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    read = getline(&line, &len, fp);
    char *a = strtok(line, ",");
    char *b = strtok(NULL, ",");
    char *custName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
    double custBudget = atof(b);
    strcpy(custName, a);

    struct Customer customer = {custName, custBudget};

    while((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        char *c = strtok(line, ",");
        char *d = strtok(NULL, ",");
        int custQuantity = atoi(d);
        char * custProduct = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
        strcpy(custProduct, c);
        customer.product[customer.index++] = productItem;
        customer.quantity += custQuantity;
    }
    return customer;
}

void printCustomer(struct Customer c)
{
    printf("CUSTOMER NAME: %s \nCUSTOMER BUDGET: %.2f\n", c.name, c.budget);
    printf("___________________\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < c.index; i++)
    {
        struct Customer product = c.product[i];
        printf("%s ORDERS %d of %s\n", c.name, c.quantity, c.product);
    }
}
```